# LINQ: Order By Count of Unique Items in List<string>

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting, count, ienumerable

I have a list of ids properly stored in a List<>.  I now need to Group this list and get a count of the number of occurrences sorted descending.

Example:

```
List<string> aryIDs = new List<string>;
aryIDs.Add("1234");
aryIDs.Add("4321");
aryIDs.Add("3214");
aryIDs.Add("1234");
aryIDs.Add("4321");
aryIDs.Add("1234");
```

Would Produce:

```
"1234", 3
"4321", 2
"3214", 1
```

This would be easy in TSQL, but I would like to avoid the server roundtrip, unnecessary tables, etc. if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Update:  The VB.NET conversion for Ralph Shillington's answer below:

```
Dim result = From id In aryIDs _
                     Group id By id Into Group _
                     Order By Group.Count() Descending _
                     Select id, Count = Group.Count()

result.Dump()
```

Comment: You mention T-SQL... You mean, all this data is in the database? Why not fetch it already grouped and sorted? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
List<string> aryIDs = new List<string>();
aryIDs.Add("1234");
aryIDs.Add("4321");
aryIDs.Add("3214");
aryIDs.Add("1234");
aryIDs.Add("4321");
aryIDs.Add("1234"); 

var result =     from id in aryIDs
group id by id into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id=g.Key, Count=g.Count() };

result.Dump();
```

Cut and paste that into LinqPad and you should be good to go.

It could also be written using Lambda expressions as:

```
aryIDs.GroupBy (id => id).OrderByDescending (id => id.Count()).Select(g => new { Id=g.Key, Count=g.Count()}).Dump();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  You even updated before I could ask for the sort.  :)

Comment: @Ralph:What is equivalent of this query statement into Lambda expression?

Comment: @santosh -- i updated the answer to include a Lambda expression as well.

Comment: @Ralph Any chance of a VB.NET conversion?  I underestimated the differences by a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

How about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#countGrouped:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();

var orderCounts =
    from c in customers
    select new { c.CustomerID, OrderCount = c.Orders.Count() };
```